# How can append data to a field in mongodb and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In this data in mongodb i want to update **user**  by _id.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("aaaab51b080ddbaaaa2db6da"), 
    "user" : "1111", 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("aaaab564ef9aaaa640adf2a9"), 
    "user" : "2222"
}
```

But  i want  this output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("aaaab51b080ddbaaaa2db6da"), 
    "user" : "1111", 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("aaaab564ef9aaaa640adf2a9"), 
    "user" : "2222Helooword"   //user + "Helooword"
}
```

I mean **user +"Helooword"**. I want append **"Helooword"** to **user**.
I use this code but it dose not work.
I want to use ***ONE query*** .(findOneAndUpdate)

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var o_id = new ObjectID("aaaab564ef9aaaa640adf2a9");
array.findOneAndUpdate
(
    { '_id' : o_id    },
    {$set:{ user:['$user','Helooword']}}, //output:"user":"$user,heeeeeeeeo",
    function (error, success) 
    {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        if(success == null )
            console.log("nullllllllllllllllllllllll");
        console.log(success);
    }
);
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to use findOneAndUpdate for you??

Comment: yes dear Kashan ali

Comment: @Syed-Kashan-Ali(irani)  i want to use one query. an efficient step to update my data. if you can use another method you can tell me.

Answer (score 0):

For now, the answer is **you can't do this** in a [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field) question for other options/ideas.